# Finding specific string patterns in tar files but then extracting those specific files

Tags: unix, save, tar, extract

So I wanted to make a new thread so I wasn't asking 2 questions on one page-

I was given a solution to searching and finding patterns and strings of files in a tar ball without extracting it:

This is what I was given:

```
tar xzf archive.tgz --to-command \
    'grep --label="$TAR_FILENAME" -H PATTERN ; true'
```

I'm kind of lost on how to interpret this- is this something I can put in a script? Also, how do I go about piping the specific file to be extracted to a specific location?

I have this as of now (for a script), but I don't know if this is correct:

```
TAR_FILENAME=$1
PATTERN=$2

tar xzf archive.tgz --to-command \
    'grep --label="$TAR_FILENAME" -H PATTERN ; true'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small script you could probably use for that:

```
TAR_FILENAME=$1
PATTERN=$2

for i in $(tar -tf $TAR_FILENAME | grep -v '/$') ; do
    if tar xOzf test.tar.gz $i | grep -q "$PATTERN" ; then
      tar xzf $i ;
    fi ;
done
```

It should do what you want.

Now let me start the explainations with your own lines:

```
tar xzf archive.tgz --to-command \
  'grep --label="$TAR_FILENAME" -H $PATTERN ; true'
```

The first line extracts (`x`) a file whose name is in `$TAR_FILENAME` (`f`) and compressed with gzip (`z`); it pipes it to an external command from `tar` (`--to-command`).

So actually it does extract your tarball, but data is not written to your disk; instead it's sent to the `grep` command, which search for `$PATTERN`.
The options `--label=` and `-H` are for printing the name of the tarball (but NOT the original file in which the pattern is found) (see documentation for grep in manual page for details).

If `grep` finds at least one occurence of `$PATTERN` it returns 0 at the end of its execution; otherwise, it returns 1, which is interpreted by `tar` as an error value. To prevent this, we ensure that the external command called by `tar` returns 0: we call `true`.

So what you code does is: extracting all files and piping it to grep, looking for your pattern, and print occurences of this pattern along with the name of your tarball.

Now, let's examine my suggestion with pseudo-code:

```
for all files in tarball, do
  extract file to standard output and pipe it to grep
  use grep to search $PATTERN
  if $PATTERN is found
    extract this file to disk
  endif
endfor
```

Details:

```
tar -tf $TAR_FILENAME | grep -v '/$'
```

prints the list of files in tarball and excludes (`-v` option for `grep`) files ending with `/`, *i.e.* directories (we don't want to pipe directories in `grep`).

So we print this list and run a `for` loop upon it: for all thoose files, exract them to standard output (`O` option for `tar`) and search for `$PATTERN`. The `-q` option prevents `grep` from printing `$PATTERN`: we just want to know if it is found or not.
If a `$PATTERN` is found, `grep` returns 0 so we proceed to extraction of the file:

```
tar xzf $i
```

Else, nothing happens and we continue with next file.